# How to send an email with a PDF through a script inside google spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-sheets-api

The script just works as I want, I didn't develop it, I forgot the author's site, sorry if I don´t mention he/she.

The big problem is that I´m unable or I can't figure out how can I send an email with the PDF created through the script, I don't want to sent it in Zip format and if you release, the PDF file name´s change every time you use the spreadsheet, here I leave the code:

```
    function spreadsheetToPDF(){

  var key = '1hBbCnmca_wx4wbQx93Vf4d9cfUwGbFSP9hKgv9Qu7Vk';  //docid

  var index = 0;  //sheet gid / number


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');

  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'-'HHmm");
  var plainonum = ActiveSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();  //order number
  var supp_name = ActiveSheet.getRange("C12").getValue();  //supplier
  var onum = ('0000' + plainonum ).slice(-4);  //sets leading zeros to order number
  var description = ActiveSheet.getRange("C18").getValue();  //description
  var email = ActiveSheet.getRange("D1").getValue(); //email

  var name = 'Order-' + onum +'-' + supp_name + '-' + description + '-' + timestamp + '.pdf';  //makes pdf filename


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  //ensures everything on spreadsheet is "done"

  //make the pdf from the sheet
  var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
  + key 
  + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&notes=false'
  + '&size=letter'
  + '&portrait=true'
  + '&fitw=true'       // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
  + '&gridlines=false'
  + '&fzr=false'      // do not repeat frozen rows on each page
  + '&gid='
  + index;       //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
  var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(name).getAs('application/pdf');


  //save the file to folder on Drive
  var fid = '0B6iePPHdQRoxQVB3eERrb1c3MUE';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
  folder.createFile(pdf);
  var pfd = DriveApp.getFileById(pdf.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:name,content:pfd, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Here I need to send the email
  // GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "The subject", "The body content") // AND The PDF File witch I can´t attach

  //Show a Popup with a message that a file was created inside a folder

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New document created in' + ' ' + folder);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the file from drive using the [`DriveApp.getFolderById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid), you may then send it as an attachment using [`MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body).

Here's the sample code that you can try:

```
// Send an email with two attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Insert any HTML content here', 'text/html', 'my_document.html');
 MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
 });
```

Solution given in this [SO post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/send-an-email-with-attachment-using-google-apps-script) might also help.

Comment: Hi, well, I can´t get the file by ID because is a PDF file created just in the moment the script runs and it makes a diferent file name every time the script is executed because of the parameters given in the construction of the file, plus the function getAs is sending me an error. "can´t find the function getAs..."

Comment: Hi, I already solve the problem, as I suspected I was emailing only the name of the file but without the content, so here is the var I created under the folder creation:
var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, I was emailing only the name of the file but without the content, so I made a little variation to the var under the folder creation:
var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

```
// Create a PDF from the active sheet, save it under a specific directory and send the PDF by mail

  function spreadsheetToPDF(){

  var key = 'abcdefghijk1234567890';  //docid (actual spreadsheet)

  var index = 0;  //sheet gid / number


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');

  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'-'HHmm");
  var plainonum = ActiveSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();  //order number
  var supp_name = ActiveSheet.getRange("C12").getValue();  //supplier
  var onum = ('0000' + plainonum ).slice(-4);  //sets leading zeros to order number
  var description = ActiveSheet.getRange("C18").getValue();  //description
  var correo = ActiveSheet.getRange("D1").getValue(); //correo electrónico

  var name = 'Order-' + onum +'-' + supp_name + '-' + description + '-' + timestamp + '.pdf';  //makes pdf filename


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  //ensures everything on spreadsheet is "done"

  //make the pdf from the sheet
  var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
  + key 
  + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&size=A4'
  + '&portrait=true'
  + '&fitw=true'       // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
  + '&gridlines=false'
  + '&fzr=false'      // do not repeat frozen rows on each page
  + '&gid='
  + index;       //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
  var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(name).getAs('application/pdf');



  //save the file to folder on Drive
  var fid = 'abcdefghij1234567890';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
  folder.createFile(pdf);

  //get the file, name and content to send it by email

  var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(); 
  var attach = {fileName:name,content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};


  // Send email with the PDF attached
  GmailApp.sendEmail(correo, "The subject", "The body content", {attachments:[attach]});


  //Show a Popup with a message that a file was created inside a folder

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Nuevo Documento creado en el folder' + ' ' + folder);

}
```